# Traefik v2: redirect http://servername/foo to http://servername:port

Tags: docker, redirect, docker-compose, traefik, self-hosting

I have traefik (v. 2.3.5) and other services running on my raspberrypi in my home network. Each service is running on a different port on the same machine.
I want traefik to redirect a call from a subpath to a different url. Like so:

http://myServer/omv --> http://myServer:8000
http://myServer/heimdall --> http://myServer:8003

However I can not make it work. My router is not offering a domain/subdomains so I have to live with subpathes instead.

OMV is installed locally so I have created a file provider and that is the only one that is working. I cannot find out what I'm doing wrong with my docker-compose files for e.g. heimdall.

Here is the **traefik docker-compose.yml**:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
        traefik:
                image: traefik:latest
                container_name: traefik
                restart: unless-stopped
                security_opt:
                        - no-new-privileges:true
                ports:
                        - 80:80
                volumes:
                        - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
                        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
                        - /root/myDockers/traefik/data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
                        - /root/myDockers/traefik/data/non-docker-services.yml:/non-docker-services.yml:ro

                labels:
                        - "traefik.enable=true"
                        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
                        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/traefik`)" 
                        - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=XXXX:YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
                        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-auth,traefik-strip-prefix"
                        - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-strip-prefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/traefik"
                        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
```

**Traefik.yml:**

```yaml
api:
        dashboard: true
#        insecure: true
        debug: true

log:
        format: json
        level: DEBUG
accessLog:
       format: common
entryPoints:
        http:
                address: ":80"

providers:
        docker:
          endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
          exposedByDefault: false
          watch: true
        file:
          filename: /non-docker-services.yml
          watch: true
```

**non-docker-services.yml:**

```yaml
http:
  routers:
    omv:
      entryPoints:
        - "http"
      rule: "PathPrefix(`/omv`)"
      service: omv
      middlewares:
        - omv-rr
  middlewares:
    omv-rr:
      redirectRegex:
        regex: "^http://myServer/omv(.*)"
        replacement: "http://myServer:8000${1}"
        permanent: true
  services:
    omv:
     loadBalancer:
       servers:
         - url: "http://myServer:8000"
       passHostHeader: true
```

**heimdall docker-compose.yml:**

```yaml
version: "2"
services:
        heimdall:
                image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/heimdall
                container_name: heimdall
                environment:
                        - PUID=1000
                        - PGID=1000
                        - TZ=Europe/Berlin
                volumes:
                        - /root/myDockers/heimdall/appdata/config:/config
                ports:
                        - 8003:80
                restart: unless-stopped
                labels:
                        - "traefik.enable=true"
                        - "traefik.hppt.routers.heimdall.entrypoints=http"
                        - "traefik.http.routers.heimdall.rule=PathPrefix(`/heimdall`)"
                        - "traefik.http.routers.heimdall.middlewares=heimdall-redirect"
                        - "traefik.http.middlewares.heimdall-redirect.redirectregex.regex=`^http://myServer/heimdall(.*)`"
                        - "traefik.http.middlewares.heimdall-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=`http://myServer:8003`"
                        - "traefik.http.middlewares.heimdall-redirect.redirectregex.permanent=true"
                        - "traefik.http.services.heimdall.loadbalancer.server.url=`http://myServer:8003`"
```

When I call http://myServer/heimdall nothing happens, after sometime I get a time out. I think the reason is, that traefik is trying to forward
to the docker internal network address of heimdall 172.31.0.2:80 which is of course not reachable from my client. In the traefik log it states:
traefik    | {"entryPointName":"http","level":"debug","msg":"Creating server 0 [http://172.31.0.2:80","routerName":"heimdall@docker","serverName":0,"serviceName":"heimdall","time":"2020-12-13T21:55:02+01:00"}](http://172.31.0.2:80%22,%22routerName%22:%22heimdall@docker%22,%22serverName%22:0,%22serviceName%22:%22heimdall%22,%22time%22:%222020-12-13T21:55:02+01:00%22%7D)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further google work I think I found the answer in this forum post: https://community.traefik.io/t/traefik-v2-1-4-how-to-create-a-static-route-and-redirect-to-a-specific-host-and-port/4637

What they say there is, that you can only route to the docker container itself if you are using docker labels to configure traefik. For routing outside of the docker container, you need to use a docker file provider.
This also explains why it is working for me with OMV but not for heimdall.

Answer (score 0):

can you check "Host" at "traefik.http.routers.heimdall.rule"

maybe it needs to be like this,

```
"traefik.http.routers.heimdall.rule=Host(`myServer`) && PathPrefix(`/heimdall`)"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but it did not work either...